# Click event for each item in a loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need some help to get a jQuery click function to work for all items I am outputting with a PHP while loop. It only works on the first loop.

I need to open a popup window to display a message to the user when they trigger the click function.

PHP:

```
<?php


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_mem='$from_mem' AND
              to_mem_burn='2' AND new_message='3' ORDER BY id DESC");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($num_rows < 1) {
    echo '<div id="new_message" class="addlinkuplinks a">&nbsp;You have no 
               message at this time.&nbsp;</div>';
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $msg_id = $row['id'];
        $msg_to_mem = $row['to_mem'];
        $msg_from_mem = $row['from_mem'];
        $msg_from_memID = $row['from_memID'];
        $msg_subject = $row['subject'];
        $msg_content = $row['content'];
        $msg_date = $row['date'];
        $msg_from_mem_burn = $row['from_mem_burn'];
        $msg_to_mem_burn = $row['to_mem_burn'];

        $sqlName=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email<>'$from_mem' 
            AND email='$msg_from_mem' LIMIT 1")or die ("Sorry we have a mysql error!");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlName)){
            $msg_from_memAccount=$row["accountType"];
            $msg_from_memID=$row["hdw_id"];
            $msg_from_memfirstName=$row["firstName"];
            $msg_from_memlastName=$row["lastName"];
            $msg_from_mem_pic=$row["profile_pic"];
            $gender=$row["gender"];

        }

        echo '

     <div id="linkUPmsg" class="linkUPmsg"> 
     <table width="100%">
       <tr>
       <tr><td width="60%"align="left" valign="top"><span style="font-size:
                12px; color: #CCCCCC;">Read Date:</span></td>
     <td width="40%"align="right" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 12px; color: 
     #CCCCCC;">'.$msg_date.'</span></td>
       </tr>
     <table width="100%">
     <tr>
     <td width="5%" align="left">'.$profile_pic.'</td>
      <td width="87%"align="left" ><span style="font-size: 14px; font-
         weight: bold; color:#999999;">'.$msg_from_memfirstName.' 
           '.$msg_from_memlastName.'</span>      
      <div id="requestlinkUP_text">Send you this message!</div>
      <div id="requestlinkUP_text"">Subject: <span style="font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold; color: #0066CC;">'.$msg_subject.'</span></div>
      </td>

     <div id="member_msg"></div>
     <td width="3%" align="right"><div id="linkUPmsg_read"
              class="msgAction"">
     <a href="#"><img src="/image/read_mail.png" width="41"
                    height="27" /></a>
     </div>
             <div id="popupboxrContact">      

    <div id="memberslinkup" class="msgdiv"></div>
    <div id="formbox" class="form_border" >

    <div class="tittle_border"><table width="100%" bgcolor="#F30"
             style="opacity: 0.7;">
  <tr>
<td>
 <a id="popupboxrContactClose" class="popupboxClose">Close</a>
 <span style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color:
#CCC;">Reading Message</span></td>
  </tr>
</table></div><p></p>   
   <p></p> 

<table width="100%">
       <tr>
       <tr><td width="60%"align="left" valign="top"><span style="font-size:
       12px; color: #CCCCCC;">Read Date:</span></td>
     <td width="40%"align="right" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 12px; color:
            #CCCCCC;">'.$msg_date.'</span></td>
       </tr>
     <table width="100%">
     <tr>
     <td width="5%" align="left">'.$profile_pic.'</td>
      <td width="87%"align="left" ><span style="font-size: 14px; font-
    weight: bold; color: #999999;">'.$msg_from_memfirstName.' 
                '.$msg_from_memlastName.'</span>
      <div id="requestlinkUP_text">Send you this message!</div>
      <div id="requestlinkUP_text"">Subject: <span style="font-size: 12px;
                    font-weight: bold; color: #0066CC;">'.$msg_subject.'</span></div>
      </td>
</tr>
</table>


        </div>      
</div>  
<div id="bgPopupboxr"></div>
     </td>

     <div id="member_msg"></div>
     <td width="3%" align="right"><div id="linkUPmsg_read" 
      class="addlinkuplinks"><form id="readForm" action="" class="form" method=""
                      enctype="multipart/form-data" name="acceptlinkUP">
     <input name="read_linkUPmsg" class="msgAction" type="image"
           src="/image/mail_reply.png" /></form></div></a>
     </td>

     <div id="member_msg"></div>
      <td width="2%" align="right"><div id="linkUPmsg_burn"
  class="addlinkuplinks"><form id="burnForm" action="/burn_message.php" class="form"
     method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="burnlinkUP">
      <input name="msg_id" type="hidden" value="'.$msg_id.'" />
      <input name="to_mem" type="hidden" value="'.$msg_from_mem.'" />
     <input name="burn_linkUPmsg" class="msgAction" type="image"
             src="/image/burn_sign.png" />
     </form></div></a> 
    </td>

      </tr>
      </table>
      </span>
      </div>
      &nbsp;
      ';


    }
}

?>
```

jQuery:

```
var popupboxrStatus = 0;

function loadPopupboxr(){ 
    if(popupboxrStatus==0){
        $("#bgPopupboxr").css({
            "opacity": "0.4"
        });
        $("#bgPopupboxr").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupboxrContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupboxrStatus = 1;
    }
}

function disablePopupboxr(){
    if(popupboxrStatus==1){
        $("#bgPopupboxr").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupboxrContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupboxrStatus = 0;
    }
}

function centerPopupboxr(){
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupboxrHeight = $("#popupboxrContact").height();
    var popupboxrWidth = $("#popupboxrContact").width();

    $("#popupboxrContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupboxrHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupboxrWidth/2
    });

    $("#bgPopupboxr").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".msgAction").click(function(){
        //center
        centerPopupboxr();
        //load popupBox
        loadPopupboxr();
    });

    $("#popupboxrContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopupboxr();
    });
    $("#bgPopupboxr").click(function(){
        disablePopupboxr();
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont see any PHP code,  so where is your problem?

Comment: Where is the while loop?

Comment: no problem with the php code, only like to know how to apply jquery to php while loop

Comment: From what it looks like your'e talking about `$(".msgAction")`(that is the only thing the jQuery and HTML have in common) and a popup that opens up when you click on it, so do you want to show a different popup for every button?

Comment: For us to tell you how to do something with a php loop you'll need to include that loop(php) and tell us what is `not working`

Comment: @Shedokan yes am talking about $(".msgAction") it will be the same info. and popup but it will be in a php loop, example getting 10 message and you click on each one to read the message, the message will appear in the popup box.

Comment: @kasagi: where is your question ? please  elaborate your question for getting the answer's ...

Comment: You can't execute server side code directly in button click. What you're after is called AJAX.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard i just only want the popup window to work on all of the loops not just the first one.

Comment: What loop? Sorry, but can't see any loop anywhere. (You said "you click on each one to read the message" so this led me to my above comment)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard sorry i'm getting error when posting my php code. i needed 10 reputation to post image. Since problem i'm having is getting the jquery popup box to work on more than one loop, i thought someone could help without the php code because it is not the problem.

Comment: Post it as text, not image. Post only the relevant part of the loop, not your whole code.

Comment: I updated your question so that it's moderately understandable, and I upvoted so you get a bit more reputation. Once it hits 10 you should post a screenshot.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, i've add the php while loop code

Comment: From what I see, the loop is not really relevant. What you need is to display each message title/name and have it as link passing unique ID to popup window, where you read the proper message and show all its details.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, thanks for your help, i get it to work now. I was using the div id for the trigger, now i used the div class and it work. thanks again for helping me.

Comment: Didn't really help after all, but glad you got it sorted. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, You have any ideas how to get it to show proper message

Comment: What you mean "proper messages"? Thought you said you got it to work.. ?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, when place all var in the message, example $subject, $content, and $name etc. it show all the message the same as the first message.

Comment: Post your most recent code where you're using those vars (e.g. `msg_content`) and maybe we can see something you missed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see none of the html code is inside the html loop, move the ending brace that is before `echo '` and put it after the HTML.

-

I found this by reformatting your code and found this:

```
 $gender=$row["gender"];}
```

That's a hidden brace, it happens because of poor formatting.